# CMake can find one Boost header file but not another

Tags: c++, cmake, header-files

Since Boost libraries can be individually installed on some system (even though it's probably going to be rare) I want to make sure they are available.

I do that by checking for some of the header files I need:

```
check_include_file_cxx(boost/parameter/keyword.hpp HAVE_BOOST_PARAMETER_KEYWORD_HPP)
check_include_file_cxx(boost/asio/io_service.hpp HAVE_BOOST_ASIO_IO_SERVICE_HPP)
```

The problem I have is that CMake claims that it can find the `boost/parameter/keyword.hpp` header file but not the `boost/asio/io_service.hpp` header file:

```
-- Looking for C++ include boost/parameter/keyword.hpp
-- Looking for C++ include boost/parameter/keyword.hpp - found
-- Looking for C++ include boost/asio/io_service.hpp
-- Looking for C++ include boost/asio/io_service.hpp - not found
```

And yes the ASIO header file exists:

```
$ ls -l /usr/include/boost/asio/io_service.hpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 861 nov 13 13:47 /usr/include/boost/asio/io_service.hpp
```

I have Boost 1.67 installed, and an using CMake version 3.12.3 on a Debian SID system (up to date).

Is this a bug in the `check_include_file_cxx` function or am I missing something?

Comment: What are CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log and CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log saying?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Doh forgot to check, it helped me find out why, including the solution.

Comment: Arf, that's the first thing I look at, and it usually is quite clear if there is a link library missing ;)

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Yeah it should have been the first thing I did as well, bad me. Still I'll keep the question as it might help someone else lazy person in the future.

Comment: Most definitely. I also added another idiomatic way of setting a state for more generic checks, not just includes.

Comment: Why would something like `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS program_options asio system)` be insufficient?  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html

Comment: @John Because Boost ASIO is really a header-only library, and the [FindBoost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) module only looks for linker libraries. It will complain if you pass it a header-only library like `asio`.

Comment: @John And for header only lib, you may still end up with a valid Boost, but you want a version that has the header you want (OK, I agree that you can ask a specific version, but then sometimes some libs are removed, so checking the existence is safer on top of the version). And the trick is not only for checking includes, but also for other flags, as indicated in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost ASIO depends on the Boost System library, which is a link-library.

Since the CMake function `check_include_file_cxx` does a full build (including linking, not only compiles) of the the test program, it will fail unless the Boost System library is added for the linking.

That causes the test to fail, even though the header file is actually installed.

To succeed the Boost System library must be linked when checking the header file:

```
check_include_file_cxx(boost/asio/io_service.hpp HAVE_BOOST_ASIO_IO_SERVICE_HPP -lboost_system)
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for headers that require a library like Boost.ASIO, there is also another way using states. I encountered this when checking address sanitizer, and this is a portable way for checking includes and other flags as well:

First you need this module:

```
include(CMakePushCheckState)
```

Then you can push and pop check states:

```
cmake_push_check_state()
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -fsanitize=address")
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-fsanitize=address" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_ADDRESS_SANITIZER)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_ADDRESS_SANITIZER)
  message(STATUS"The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} supports -    fsanitize=address.")
else(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_ADDRESS_SANITIZER)
  message(FATAL "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} doesn't support -fsanitize=address.")
endif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_ADDRESS_SANITIZER)
cmake_pop_check_state()
```

In this case, it would be:

```
cmake_push_check_state()
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -lboost_system")
check_include_file_cxx(boost/asio/io_service.hpp HAVE_BOOST_ASIO_IO_SERVICE_HPP)
cmake_pop_check_state()
```